# jQuery offset seems not to work anymore

Tags: jquery

edits in *italic*

*answer in short words: jQuery cant handle `display:none` object position but can handle `visability`, did you change that?*

I ask this question, and want to answer it by my self, to prevent others to rush in the same pitfall as I did.

I have (had) a working solution for positioning a `div` on page *using jQuery and* `$(e).offset` *method. the first steps where fine, then* After making my script more jQuery conform (move from JavaScript to jQuery), *the* `offset`*seemed not to work anymore* -  although I did not knew the problem. *My elements where moving arround unpredictably*

I spent hours already, but cannot find the leak.

Comment: I hate to see you getting downvotes when you have posted this just to help other people, but presumably whoever downvoted didn't like the fact that your "question" and "answer" are both rather confusing. Perhaps if you edited the question to clearly state the problem you were having, like "The `.offset()` method doesn't seem to work when my elements are hidden. How do I work around this?" (or something like that) and show a few lines of related code. Although a question that can be answered simply by referring to the API documentation is likely to get downvoted or closed anyway.

Comment: @nnnnnn: I see the missing 'who can use it' in the question - I'll try to correct that. I was too much in my mind. (and pitfall, its not easy to explain how you stepped in ;-))

Comment: @halfbit I wouldn't recommend notating edits in italics, because it really just looks like you are trying to provide emphasis on those sections of text, which doesn't make much sense given the context of your question.  If you want to say what you changed, keep it simple at the end of your question and just note something like, "(Edited for clarification)" or something like that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

look at: [jQuery doc (Note: jQuery does not ...)](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)

jQuery does not like the offset of (display:none) invisible elements

If you had a working show/hide/position logic that was based on the `visible` attribute, ie. `visible:hide` showing it later, you **can't** use `jQuery $(...).show/hide`. You have to switch to/use `display:none` in your css, because jQuery takes this attribute to managen"visibility".

The - most of the time - easiest thing is to `$(...).show` your element before working with `$(...).offset(...)` (show it then move it), not use this at last action in your script (move it then show it)

HTH, it took me a lot of time to find that, since I was searching at wrong places ...